# Dirac Bilinear Transformation Laws (vector)

Tags: spinors, dirac-matrices

The question is to verify that the following Dirac Bilinears obey the following transformation law:

$$\bar\psi'(x') \gamma^\mu \psi'(x') = \Lambda^\mu_\nu \bar\psi(x) \gamma^\nu \psi(x)$$

What I know so far that may be relevant to this problem:

$$ S(\Lambda) \text{ (for the topic of spinors) is hermitian and unitary. Therefore S^2=1}$$
$$S\gamma^0=\gamma^0S$$
$$\gamma^0=S^{-1}\gamma^0S$$
$$\bar\psi\gamma^0\psi \text{ is a vector}$$
$$\psi'(x') = S(\Lambda) \psi(x)$$
$$\bar\psi = \psi^\dagger \gamma^0$$
$$S^{-1}(\Lambda) = S(\Lambda^{-1}) \text{so we will make no distinction in the two and abbreviate accordingly}$$
$$\Lambda_\mu^\nu = (\Lambda^{-1})^\mu_\nu $$
$$S \gamma^\mu S^{-1} = \Lambda_\mu^\nu \gamma^\nu$$
$$S^{-1}i \gamma^\mu S \Lambda ^\mu_\nu=\gamma^\nu$$

Note, we will make the following abbreviations:
$$S(\Lambda)= S$$
$$ \psi(x) = \psi$$
Etc .

My attempt at the problem:

$$\bar\psi'(x') \gamma^\mu \psi'(x') = \Lambda^\mu_\nu \bar\psi(x) \gamma^\nu \psi(x)$$
$$\bar\psi' \gamma^\mu \psi' = \Lambda^\mu_\nu \bar\psi \gamma^\nu \psi$$
$$\psi'^\dagger \gamma^0 \gamma^\mu \psi' = \Lambda^\mu_\nu \psi^\dagger \gamma^0 \gamma^\nu \psi$$
$$(S\psi)^\dagger \gamma^0 \gamma^\mu S\psi = \Lambda^\mu_\nu \psi^\dagger \gamma^0 \gamma^\nu \psi$$
$$\psi^\dagger S^\dagger \gamma^0 \gamma^\mu S\psi = \Lambda^\mu_\nu \psi^\dagger \gamma^0 \gamma^\nu \psi$$
$$\psi^\dagger \gamma^0 S^\dagger  \gamma^\mu S\psi = \Lambda^\mu_\nu \psi^\dagger \gamma^0 \gamma^\nu \psi$$
$$\psi^\dagger \gamma^0 S^\  \gamma^\mu S\psi = \Lambda^\mu_\nu \psi^\dagger \gamma^0 \gamma^\nu \psi$$
$$\psi^\dagger S^{-1}\gamma^0S S^\dagger  \gamma^\mu S\psi = \Lambda^\mu_\nu \psi^\dagger S^{-1}\gamma^0S \gamma^\nu \psi$$
$$\psi^\dagger S^{-1}\gamma^0  \gamma^\mu S\psi = \Lambda^\mu_\nu \psi^\dagger S^{-1}\gamma^0S \gamma^\nu \psi$$

At this point I am quite lost and I don't know what to do.

Comment: @G. Smith Ahh good points, I will edit my post accordingly, still stuck though.

Comment: @G. Smith I am writing the fact as presented from Fradkin's QFT lecture chapter 2 page 18. He Notes that $$S(\Lambda) \gamma^\mu S(\Lambda)^{-1} = (\Lambda^{-1})^\mu_\nu \gamma^\nu$$ shows that S (matrix) is hermitian. I don't quite understand it.

Comment: @G. Smith Edits completed, thank you for pointing those things out.

Comment: @G. Smith One of the things that prevents me from moving forward is that I don't know what will commute and what I can just move around freely as a scalar.